# hibernate query to get 4 counts from Users table

Tags: groovy, hibernate-criteria

I have users table , I want to create a single query using Hibernate to count employees and consultants which are departing and already departed. The employeeid field of consultants starts with "c_..." unlike employees.
Also departing are users which have 'sunsetdate' field value in future upto 30 days, departed users are users with sunsetdate field value before todays date.
if Users is the domain class with employeeid, sunsetdate as fields can I have one single query to get all the 4 counts.
Right now I am trying to do this using Criteria api but with 4 individual queries.
Something like below: (for departed consultants)

```
 def resultList =   Users.createCriteria.list(){
          like('employeeid','c_%')
          le('sunsetdate',todaysDate)
          projections {
          count(employeeid)
             }
            }
```

I want to if possible combine all 4 such queries into 1 single query
Thanks in advance

Comment: could you tag which language you are using?

Comment: i don't know groovy but if there are DetachedCriterias you could formulate 4 Queries and then make a fake query which returns 1 row and use projection subqueries to execute the detached crits in the select clause